# How to make Ctrl-PgUp and Ctrl-Pg down work when doing find in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

When I try to find content in a Microsoft Word 2010 document (using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> and the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> keyboard shortcuts do not seem to work as in earlier versions of Word.

The microsoft [kb 983049](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983049)  suggests 4 workarounds, which all include clicking with the mouse:

- Close the Navigation pane.
- Use the mouse, and then click somewhere in the body of the Word document.
- Click the <kbd>down-arrow</kbd> next to Find in the Editing group on the Home tab, click Advanced Find, and then click Cancel.
- In the Navigation pane, click the Find Options and additional search commands <kbd>down-arrow</kbd>, click Advanced Find, and then click Cancel.

**Question:** How can I still use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> without using the mouse, and keeping my hands on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Use the classic Find and Replace dialogue box (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) instead of the Navigation pane.

Type the string right after you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Word now has retuned to the document and highlighted an instance of the string which is also stored for quick search. Therefore, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PgUP</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

Comment: Ah, good alternative. A tiny downside is that you don't have the advantage of the navigation pane showing where the strings where found (if that's what you care about)

Comment: I've never liked the Navigation pane because it was designed for mouse users, so I don't know what advantage it provides :) Always using the classic Find and Replace

Answer (score 0):

If you use **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>** (or 3 times <kbd>F6</kbd>), you switch to the document (instead of the find/navigation pane) and then you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd>.

So the sequence becomes:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. Type text to search
3. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
4. Now you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd>